# mostrar un campo sabiendo su nombre en una plantilla django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

si tengo un modelo "persona" con un campo "nombre" para mostrar el campo en un template utilizo

{{persona.nombre}}

Pero como se hace cuando tengo el nombre del campo en una variable. Por ejemplo:

```
nombrecampo='nombre'    
{{persona[nombrecampo]}}
```

o más simple

```
{{persona['nombre']}}
```

evidentemente lo anterior no funciona.

He encontrado una solución creando una "template tag" personalizada es decir

```
#fichero: mi_template_tag.py    
@register.filter
def get_attr (obj,atributo):
    return getattr(obj,atributo)
```

luego en el template puedo hacer lo siguiente

```
{% import mi_template_tag %}
<p> {{persona|get_attr:'nombre'}} </p>
```

¿Debe haber una forma más sencilla de hacer esto verdad?

Comment: No, digamos que es lo que el lenguaje de template de Django soporta, digamos que su filosofía es que sea algo sencillo y entendible, y al crear objetos indexados se estarían yendo por un camino más complejo. Me parece que la mejor forma es por `getattr` tal como tienes. De hecho, si lo quisieras hacer con Python nada más, tampoco te sería posible si no es por la función `getattr`

Comment: La pregunta es: ¿por qué no haces eso en tu vista? Es parte de la filosofía de Django hacerlo así. No se ha implementado algo tan sencillo en el core de Django para poder separar las cosas en donde tienen que ir. Procesamiento en las vistas y en el template se muestra la información.

Comment: Estoy empezando y esto son pruebas que estoy haciendo para aprender. Lo que intento es pasar una lista de campos a un template para que este los muestre. Es decir le paso el nombre de los campos en el contexto que quiero que me muestre.